# How to add item to the beginning of the list in ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Is there a way to add item to a WinForms ListBox, to the beginning of the list without rewriting entire list in a loop?

Other way to solve my problem would be to display ListBox in reverse order (last item on the top) but I don't know how to do it.

My ListBox control is used as a log viewer where the most recent entry should be on the top.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert.aspx) method on the items of your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 31):

If I understand correctly, can't you use the `Insert(int index, object item)` method? For example:

```
myListBox.Items.Insert(0, "First");
```

This inserts "First" as the first item of the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use the .Sort() method of the ListBox
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort.aspx

The other of course is to put your items in a generic list and add/remove items
from that list instead of directly to the ListBox. Use the list as a datasource for your ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the sort order in your data source if you're timestamping the log events.

Answer (score 0):

I have no scientific proof to back me up here but I think a textbox is more performant in handling log visualization. 
You can also easily setup autoscrolling and if you would want to copy something, it would not require any coding.

Comment: I have already solved my problem (by using insert :P) but just for clarification - I am using listbox cause i need an easy way to add items and custom colors for every message (like error, success and so on) and I have already wrote DrawItem handler for listbox :)