# How to have a "sorted" ListBox with the first item out of order?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listbox, country

Is there an easy way to have a Sorted ListBox that automatically places a particular item "first" (out of the usual order)? For example, if I have a dynamic list of Country names, but I want a particular country first. Do I simply override the *Sort()* method to accomplish that?

One way would be to enable the *Sorted* Property, then disable it, then the Sort() Method could pick out the desired value and move it to the first position in the Items collection ([for example, using Insert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819891/how-to-add-item-to-the-beginning-of-the-list-in-listbox/819918#819918) ). **Is this the best way (or only way) to do this?**

I used to do this with the Contacts in my phone by embedding a space (or two) at the start of the item(s) I wanted first in my list. **Would that also work?**

Comment: If there was a value associated with the country names and you sorted by *that* you could make any of them the first entry by setting the value ot 0 or -1

Comment: @Plutonix Right, but if it is really a question of "alphabetical... except for *this* one" then that would be more work. This seems like such a common idiom that I don't understand why I cannot find it in a web search. But it is very hard to know how to ask for things sometimes.

Comment: Well, then put the names in a List, Sort *that*, remove The Special One, re add it at `List[0]` and use the List as a datasource

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to add items to that list once, I'd suggest to make a list with all the non-special values, sort it, and then add the special values at index 0 with `List.Insert(0, yourSpecialObj)`.

You can then put those items on the listbox.

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking, except that instead of having a separate List, just use the Items Collection of the ListBox itself.

Comment: @nocomprende Yeah that's also good. I thought that collection didn't have an insert method that's why I suggested an extra list.

Comment: just add the perfectly arranged names from the list: `myCBO.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray())` if a datasource is too hard.  @nocomprende

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by implementing your own comparer and passing into the Sort method:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

class Sorter : IComparer<Employee>
{
    public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        string nameAtTop = "Lucy";

        string xName = x.Name;

        if (x.Name.Equals(nameAtTop))
        {
            xName = "_";
        }

        string yName = y.Name;

        if (y.Name.Equals(nameAtTop))
        {
            yName = "_";
        }

        return (xName.CompareTo(yName));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Steve", Salary = 10000 });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Janet", Salary = 10000 });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Andrew", Salary = 10000 });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Bill", Salary = 500000 });
    list.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Lucy", Salary = 8000 });

    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    list.Sort(sorter);

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for. Nice.